# How to run the function on this array until I get the particular result?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I have a code to shuffle an array. I want to keep running the code on the array until the resultant array is equal to input array.

```
def riffle(deck):
    new_deck = []
    deck_1 = deck[:len(deck)//2]
    deck_2 = deck[len(deck)//2::]
    for i in range(len(deck)//2):
        new_deck.append(deck_1[i])
        new_deck.append(deck_2[i])
    if len(deck) % 2 == 1:
        new_deck.append(deck[-1])
    print(new_deck)


arr = [i for i in range(1,11)]

#t1 =time.time()
riffle(arr)
#t2 = time.time()

#

original_arr = arr[:]
k = 0
while 1:
    riffle(arr)
    if arr == original_arr:
        break
    k+= 1

print(k)
```

By running this code I am getting the output.

```
[1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 10]
[1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 10]
0
```

Is this some fault in the while loop or the function itself? Please help.

Comment: `riffle()` has absolutely no effect on the list you pass to it; it generates a new list, and just prints that rather than returning it.  This leaves you with no way to shuffle the list repeatedly.

Comment: Then how to modify the current code?

Comment: Replacing the contents of the passed list with the shuffled version (`deck[:] = new_deck`), at the end of `riffle()`, would probably be the simplest fix.